# How to "link" tile in XNA

Tags: xna, textures, tiles

I actually work on a little game project and I would like to increase the graphics quality of my game.
I've created a tile engine and I've actually this rendering :

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/535060NoLink.png

And I try to have :

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/796631Link.png

Cordially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you would do this with Bitmasking.

http://www.angryfishstudios.com/2011/04/adventures-in-bitmasking/

It involves a lot more work, but the results can be quite nice.  You can also do a 4 bit mask if you rather keep more simple.